# Refresh firebase auth token from chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, authentication, firebase, google-chrome-extension, firebase-authentication

I need to securely communicate to firebase functions (https endpoint) to make some requests. But this needs to be authenticated.  So I am using the [authorized-https-endpoints](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/authorized-https-endpoint/functions/index.js) to communicate to it.

Now, to login I have created a web page hosted with firebase hosting which simply logs in with `firebase-auth-ui` and after successful login, passes the access token to chrome extension. And then extension uses the token to make authenticated requests to https endpoints.

```
currentUser.getToken().then(function(data){
    var editorExtensionId = "extension-id";
    var tokenVal = data
    // Make a simple request:
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(editorExtensionId, {
           token: tokenVal
    },function(response) {
    });
```

But, this tokens, expires after 1 hour. Even, custom auth tokens also expires after an hour. So after, 1 hour all my requests failed because the token verification fails.

What can be ways I can make authenticated requests over a long period of time?

Comment: if your extension uses chrome sign-in, you could instead pass a token from chrome.identity

Comment: @Zig I m using firebase auth. Sorry but no idea about how chrome identity api works. New to chrome extensions.

Comment: Are you logging in your user using an OAuth provider on your page?

Comment: you will need to generate the firebase auth token from the extension to work with firebase auth. Else, you need to use something else. I suggested chrome.identity if your users are already signed-in to chrome. If so, look at that documentation. you can get an access token for a scope that exposes the user email. then, server-side google has an api to get information about the token, which will give you back the user email. you can also pass an access token to the tokeninfo endpoint. https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth

Comment: @Zig Thanks for explaining it. I was thinking of generating the API key for the user and sending subsequent calls with the api key to my server. Which should be fine in my case and would be secure also.